# convert date to order day of the month

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How can I convert date to the order day of the month in ORACLE?

Ex: 31/07/2000 -> "Monday, the Thirty-First of July, 2000".

Is there any format date which can solve this problem?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is - you need to combine some format elements (and modifiers) with a bit of boilerplate text (to add "the" and "of"). Like this:

```
select to_char( to_date('31/07/2000', 'dd/mm/yyyy')
              , 'fmDay, "the " Ddspth "of" Month, yyyy') as spelled_out_date
from   dual;

SPELLED_OUT_DATE                       
---------------------------------------
Monday, the  Thirty-First of July, 2000
```

Note that, while the names of days of the week and calendar months depend on your session's then-current NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE, the `Ddspth` element will always be in English. So, alas, this solution DOES NOT WORK for other languages.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked successfully. 
I had one more question, how to use TO_CHAR (0.25) without losing 0?
when I tried this, after executing, the result's ".25"

Comment: @ThúyTrần - `TO_CHAR(0.25, '0.99')` will preserve the leading 0.